# Compare And Run Code in the Background Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello everyone i want to run flutter app in the background like alarm in the mobile phone
because i want the mute the phone for a some of time
ok so when i want to get all data from sqlflite i facing error

This is the code i write in sqlite class

```
Future<void> mutephone() async {
    DateTime begin
    var db = await timedb();
    var result = await db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM time");
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot = result.toList();
    for (int i = 0; i <= snapshot.length; i++) {

      if (begin==DateTime.parse(snapshot[i]["fromtime"])) {
        print("hi");
}
```

main FUNCTION :

`await db.mutephone();`

and can i make function thats run the code every 1 second  for checking?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Timer.periodic(...)` to run code periodically (e.g. every 1 sec as in your case).

```
import 'dart:async';

Timer.periodic(
     const Duration(seconds: 1), 
     (t) => /* do your stuff */,
);
```

Comment: ok what about for the get data and compare it ? do you have any solution for this?